# How to make a reset password system in React + Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm a little lost.
I'm trying to set up a password reset system, but I'm not sure how to do it.
I don't have to send an email to create a new password.
How can I do to allow the user to change the password through this form?
In theory the new password should replace the old one saved in the Firebase database.

```
import './ResetPassword.css'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';
import { getAuth, sendPasswordResetEmail } from "firebase/auth";

function ResetPassword() {

    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const auth = getAuth();

    sendPasswordResetEmail(auth, email)
      .then(() => {
        // Password reset email sent!
        // .. 
        })
      .catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        // ..
      });



    return (
        <div className="resetPassword-main">
            <div className="resetPassword-container">
                <h2>Ripristina la password</h2>
                <div className="resetPassword-form">
                    <form onSubmit={sendPasswordResetEmail}>

                    <label>Email</label> <br />
                    <input className="resetEmailInput" placeholder="Email" type="email" required /> <br/>

                    <label>Nuova password</label> <br />
                    <input className="resetPwInput" placeholder="Password" type="password"  /> <br/>

                    <button className="resetBtn" type="submit">Ripristina password</button>

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ResetPassword;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `sendPasswordResetEmail()` is used when user is *not* logged in and needs to reset the password as they don't remember it. In that case an email containing a password reset is sent using which user can reset their password.

You don't have to ask for the new password in this form. Once the user changes the password using the email sent, it'll be updated in Firebase Auth.

Try wrapping the `sendPasswordResetEmail` code in a function e.g. `triggerResetEmail` and then call it on button click `onClick={triggerResetEmail}`:

```
function ResetPassword() {

  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const auth = getAuth();

  const triggerResetEmail = async () => {
    await sendPasswordResetEmail(auth, email);
    console.log("Password reset email sent")
  }
 
  return (
    <div className="resetPassword-main">
      // Input field for email
      <button className="resetBtn" type="button" onClick={triggerResetEmail}>Ripristina password</button>

    </div>
  )
}

export default ResetPassword;
```

Comment: I added an email input field. I tried with an email address that is already in the database and got this error:
" assert.ts:122 Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/missing-email). " and the POST 400 error saying the email is missing...

Comment: @Adele can you `console.log(email)` right before send email function and also share a screenshot of the user in your Firebase Auth?  Also what database are you referring to? The functions are for [Firebase authentication](https://firebase.google.com/products/auth), you don't need to store any user credentials in a database.

Comment: I am referring to the Firebase database. I thought the database saved credentials (email, password). I used firebase authentication to let the user to create credentials to login the platform. And it works.
added the screenshot

Comment: @Adele I cannot see email being logged so it seems to be an empty string. Can you share a screenshot of the database that you are referring to ?

Comment: Ok now it works: 
`const triggerResetEmail = async () => {
        console.log(email);
        await sendPasswordResetEmail(auth, email);
        console.log("Password reset email sent");
    }

<input className="resetEmailInput" placeholder="Email" type="email" value={email} onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} required /> `

Comment: @Adele what turned out to be the issue ?

Comment: yes. I didn't set the `value={email}` with `onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}`
The email now being sent but in spam... i don't know why

Comment: @Adele have you tried with any other email? If that still lands in spam, it might be best to check with Firebase support once.

Comment: Yes, it seems that the domain from which it sends the email is causing that problem. I hadn't changed it yet.

Answer (score 5):

> I don't have to send an email to create a new password. How can I do
> to allow the user to change the password through this form?

Since **you don't need to send an email**, you can simply use the [`updatePassword()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#updatepassword) method as follow:

```
import {
  getAuth,
  updatePassword,
} from 'firebase/auth';

const newPassword = ... // Get the value of the new password
await updatePassword(auth.currentUser, newPassword);
```

The **tricky thing is** that "this is a security sensitive operation that requires the user to have recently signed in" as explained in the doc. "If this requirement isn't met, ask the user to authenticate again and then call [`reauthenticateWithCredential()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#reauthenticatewithcredential)".

You'll get an `auth/requires-recent-login` error from the `updatePassword()` method if the user hasn't recently signed in.

In this case do as follows:

```
import {
  getAuth,
  updatePassword,
  reauthenticateWithCredential,
  EmailAuthProvider,
} from 'firebase/auth';

// ...

const oldPassword = ... // Get the value of the old password
const credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(
   this.currentUser.email,
   oldPassword
);
await reauthenticateWithCredential(auth.currentUser, credential);

// Call again updatePassword()
const newPassword = ... // Get the value of the new password
await updatePassword(auth.currentUser, newPassword);
```